# 'No supported GPU device was found on this computer' Matlab R2018a?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, nvidia

[image]

So I updated my Nvidia drivers by following this ans (https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/278938-why-can-i-not-use-my-gpu-within-matlab-for-gpu-computing).
But then I got problems with my display, and when I checked the status of my **Nvidia Geforce GT 730** in Device Manager it showed this error

**'Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems(Code 43) '**. 
Also When I try to use `gpuDevice` command, it also showed me an error message. So I downgraded my Nvidia drivers version to 391 (March 2018). Now Again error in Matlab is 'No supported GPU device was found on this computer'. I checked that my GPU is supported by Matlab from the list of Cuda enabled GPUs.

Now, I don't know what to do to make it work/ to use parallel computing toolbox Matlab?

Comment: [GT 730](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-730/specifications) comes in Fermi architecture (Compute 2.1) as well as Kepler architecture (Compute 3.5). Which one do you have? If you have the Fermi one, then MATLAB 2018a does not support it because Fermi architecture has been deprecated by NVIDIA.

Comment: You can also refer to this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got this. As [sgarizvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231073/sgarizvi) suggested that Matlab 2018a does not support Fermi architecture as given [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpu-support-by-release.html). I found that my GPU [Geforce GT 730](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NWQN7FY) has Fermi architecture. So it is not supported by Matlab 2018a.